# php class function not exist in the class

Tags: php

I'm new to php.  But I do have good understanding of oo language.  I'm running into these php codes in OpenCart application (https://www.opencart.com/).

```
class ControllerCustomerCustomerGroup extends Controller {
  private $error = array();

  public function index() {
      $this->load->language('customer/customer_group');

      $this->document->setTitle($this->language->get('heading_title'));

      $this->load->model('customer/customer_group');

      $this->getList();
  }
```

I understand that $this means the current object.  But in this class, I'm not seeing the load or document property/function.  I understand that this class inherit from the Controller class.  But I don't see those two properties/functions in the Controller class either.

Below is the complete Controller super class:

```
<?php
    abstract class Controller {
    protected $registry;

    public function __construct($registry) {
        $this->registry = $registry;
    }

    public function __get($key) {
        return $this->registry->get($key);
    }

    public function __set($key, $value) {
        $this->registry->set($key, $value);
    }
}
```

I use the intellisense in eclipse php editor and it is not seeing them either.  So, I'm lost...
[image]

Comment: which framework of php are you use ?? @HockChai

Comment: `load` & `document` are properties, if you don't see them anywhere that means they're being defined at run time. It's a poor practice to make use of public properties as you have no control what they are, and of course you run into the problem you're running into now. You have no idea where they're coming from.

Comment: @bharat.  I'm new to php.  Sorry, I don't really know what frame work is used.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about the Codeigniter framework. If you have a closer look at their `controller` class you will find

`$this->load =& load_class('Loader', 'core');`

this line. This line actually loading the `Loader` and `core` class.

Now, if you take a look at the `Loader` class you will see that the loader is has `model` method to load model. That's how it is working internally.

Comment: I just added the complete coding of the Controller super class.  I don't the load_class that you mentioned.